# Facebook create Application not showing icon when posting image or video. it showing only when post text

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I create one application on developer.facebook.com. and add 3 image 16,75 and 128. the application icon shows when i post text. but it doesnt show when i post video or image. should i make any changes in setting of the app on developer.facebook.com.
For example. in path.[image]

in my application when posting text. the app icon appear.
[image]

but when posting image or video. the app icon disappear.
[image]

[image]

Thanks for help. i have done r&d on this and i got Facebook bug so is it right?: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/447623711966656?browse=search_50bfaaaf247045772567103

Comment: I also got same error but could not resolve it...Also done lots of R&D...

Comment: There is no bug - did you read the post? It's by design. Follow the suggestions mentioned there.

Comment: @J.Steen then how its working on path. and what should we do to resolve this.

Comment: I'm just reading the *words that are written* in the post you, yourself, linked. It says to use Open Graph. Are you using Open Graph? I'm not a Facebook app developer, I just apply logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design and isn't related to your application settings. Facebook display videos and photos uploaded by applications in different ways to status updates and sharing using the share dialog.